jQuery autocomplete (ajax) not working in SPA
This works fine:


$("#Term").autocomplete({
  source: '/ws/words.json?lang=en'
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.14.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.14.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.14.0/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
<div id="myform">
  <label for="Term">Term: </label>
  <input id="Term">
</div>



But when I remove the content of the <div> and fill it later with content delivered from a server, including an <input id="Term"> (like in a single page application) the autocomplete stops working, even when I send the autocomplete script along with the new <div> content. What causes it and what can I do about it?

I'm sure there's a good duplicate somewhere, but basically you just need to initialize the plugin (the call to $( "#Term" ).autocomplete) again after adding that new element to the page.  You can't delegate plugins like you can with events.  Plugins need to be initialized on the target element(s) after those elements are added to the page.

$("#Term") only finds elements that exist at the time the code runs.  It's not a "live" or "future" query.  Run the initialisation code directly after you add the element.

But isn't that achieved already by adding the script to the new div content, as I tried?

@KrisVanBruwaene: Is that script executing when adding it to the page?  I wouldn't be surprised if some extra step needs to be taken to execute JavaScript code added to the page from an AJAX response.  But more to the point... Why bother with that in the first place?  The page already has code to initialize the plugin.  There's no need to send that same code to the browser again.  Just re-invoke it when you need to initialize that plugin.

IF you wish to remove the HTML inside the element you can do so however you would need to attach to the container instead of the element. You will however need to add the element back IN which you do not do in your example.
Here, I do that all in perhaps a bit of an ugly manor.
Consider instead just hiding the element and not overwriting the containers text instead.
What you asked:


const words = ["Hi", "By", "bye", "winter", "summer", "fall", "spring", "football", "boy", "friends"];
const template = document.getElementById("cool-auto-things");
const $myform = $("#myform");

$myform.on('add-autothings', function(event) {
  const $container = $(this);
  $container.textContent = "";
  const $termContainer = $container.find('.term-container');
  const templateClone = template.content.cloneNode(true);
  const container = document.getElementById("myform");
  const $terms = $(templateClone).find(".term");
  container.appendChild(templateClone);
  $terms.autocomplete({
    //  source: '/ws/words.json?lang=en'
    source: words
  }).on("autocompleteclose", function(event, ui) {
    const autodata = [{
      termValue: $(this).val()
    }];
    $container.trigger('got-completed', autodata);
  });
}).on('got-completed', function(event, myData) {
  const $container = $(this);
  $container.text($container.find('.term').val());
}).trigger('add-autothings');
.page-container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  margin: 1em;
}

.my-form {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #00ff0022;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.14.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" integrity="sha512-F8mgNaoH6SSws+tuDTveIu+hx6JkVcuLqTQ/S/KJaHJjGc8eUxIrBawMnasq2FDlfo7FYsD8buQXVwD+0upbcA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.14.0/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha512-MlEyuwT6VkRXExjj8CdBKNgd+e2H+aYZOCUaCrt9KRk6MlZDOs91V1yK22rwm8aCIsb5Ec1euL8f0g58RKT/Pg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div class="page-container">
  <div id="myform" class="my-form"></div>
</div>
<template id="cool-auto-things">
  <label class="term-container">Term: <input class="term" /></label>
</template>



Hide instead of removing it/replacing with text - what you really meant to ask it feels like:


const words = ["Hi", "By", "bye", "winter", "summer", "fall", "spring", "football", "boy", "friends"];
const template = document.getElementById("cool-auto-things");
const templateClone = template.content.cloneNode(true);
const container = document.getElementById("myform");
const $myform = $("#myform");
const $terms = $(templateClone).find(".term");
container.appendChild(templateClone);
$terms.autocomplete({
  //  source: '/ws/words.json?lang=en'
  source: words
}).on("autocompleteclose", function(event, ui) {
  const autodata = [{
    termValue: $(this).val()
  }];
  $(this).closest('.my-form').trigger('got-completed', autodata);
}).focus();

$(".start-over").on("click", function(event) {
  $myform.trigger('add-autothings');
});

$myform.on('add-autothings', function(event) {
  const $container = $(this);
  const $termContainer = $container.find('.term-container');
  $container.find('.term-text').hide();
  const $term = $termContainer.find(".term");
  $term.val("");
  $termContainer.show();
  $term.focus();
}).on('got-completed', function(event, myData) {
  const $container = $(this);
  const $termContainer = $container.find('.term-container');
  $termContainer.hide();
  $(this).find('.term-text').text(myData.termValue).show();
});
.page-container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  margin: 1em;
}

.my-form {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #00ff0022;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.14.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" integrity="sha512-F8mgNaoH6SSws+tuDTveIu+hx6JkVcuLqTQ/S/KJaHJjGc8eUxIrBawMnasq2FDlfo7FYsD8buQXVwD+0upbcA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.14.0/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha512-MlEyuwT6VkRXExjj8CdBKNgd+e2H+aYZOCUaCrt9KRk6MlZDOs91V1yK22rwm8aCIsb5Ec1euL8f0g58RKT/Pg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div class="page-container">
  <div id="myform" class="my-form"></div>
  <button type="button" class="start-over" data-target="#myform">Start Over</button>
</div>
<template id="cool-auto-things">
  <label class="term-container">Term: <input class="term" /></label>
  <span class="term-text"></span>
</template>




Note I used <template id="cool-auto-things"> just to avoid extra JavaScript and to keep all the HTML in HTML ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template
